# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable on a market analysis project

Tags: dataframe, plot, google-play, finance, moving-average

Code:

```
gm['MA50'] = gm['Open'].rolling(50).mean()
gm['Ma200'] = gm['Open'].rolling(200).mean()
gm('Open','MA50','MA200').plot(label='gm',figsize=(16,8))
```

I have been having the following error despite every way to change it and still getting the same error.

Error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-062557c07834> in <module>
      1 gm['MA50'] = gm['Open'].rolling(50).mean()
      2 gm['Ma200'] = gm['Open'].rolling(200).mean()
----> 3 gm('Open','MA50','MA200').plot(label='gm',figsize=(16,8))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Would need some advice to overcoming this error?

Comment: maybe you should also accompanying it with some data and more codes so that your helper may have an easier time to solve it...

Comment: by the way, did you check  out this gm[[ 'Open','MA50','MA200']].plot(label='gm',figsize=(16,8))